# C# bitmap using excessive memory when displaying in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, bitmapimage

I have a class which allows me to draw lines on a bitmap to create a crude map. When I create a large bitmap it uses the amount of memory I expect (a 10,000x10,000 image uses 400MB).

To display the image in a WPF window I have the following code:

`imageBox.Source = mapBuilder.getMapInDisplayFormat();`

Which calls

```
public BitmapImage getMapInDisplayFormat()
{
    //areaBitMap is the underlying bitmap which has been drawn
    areaBitMap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY); //Flip image in the Y axis so 0,0 is in the bottom left corner like a graph (not top left)
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        areaBitMap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        areaBitMap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY); //After saving to the mem stream flip the image back so future drawings are to the correct location
        memory.Position = 0;                
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        memory.Dispose();
    }
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

After the image is displayed the program memory usage increases to 1.2GB (3 times the memory needed to store a bitmap). I can understand the `BitmapImage` having a separate memory allocation which would require 800MB (total), but I have no idea why the memory usage is 3 times what I expected. (Note: 400MB was an example, this pattern holds true for any size bitmap, but it is only a issue with larger images). Can anyone explain why the memory usage is so high?

I took the code to convert a Bitmap to BitmapImage from a SO question. Is this the best way to display the image on screen? It seems quite inefficient. Can you natively display a bitmap without the conversion?

Comment: Freezing the BitmapImage (by calling its Freeze method) should reduce memory consumption. You could also try create a BitmapFrame from the MemoryStream. Or try [CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Freezing the BitmapImage didn't appear to change the memory usage. I will take a look at implementing CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap

Comment: Memory usage measured how? Unless you are using a memory profiler and/or have some other means of inspecting the detailed layout of your memory allocations, there's no way to know even if you actually _are_ **using** as much memory as you think. For example, intermediate allocations may involve not necessarily having three large objects in memory at once, but may still result in a heap large enough for three.

Comment: As for possible sources of the extra data usage (if genuine): I didn't look to see what the actual implementation of `RotateFlip()` is, but that easily could involve an intermediate copy of the bitmap. And then there's the space required by the `MemoryStream` object in which you're dumping the raw bitmap data (in .bmp format, so uncompressed).

Comment: I was using the memory profiling tool in VS 2015 to get the memory usage. `RotateFlip()` does appear to make a copied, but this memory appears to get cleared up. Could it be the program only has 400MB of objects in memory, but the OS allocated it 1.2GB to handle all the copies, which is then no longer available to other programs?